# Range of this double trigonometric function

Tags: derivatives

What is the range of 
$$
\sin(\cos(x)).
$$
Generally we have various methods. Like differentiation, graphical analysis. So it's range is $[0,1]$. But how to prove it using any known method or analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\cos(\mathbb{R})=[-1,1]
$$
Being $\sin$ increasing from $-\sin(1)$ to $\sin(1)$ ($0<\sin(1)<1$), then
$$ 
\sin([-1,1])=[-\sin(1),\sin(1)]
$$